# How to draw complicated shape in android, with contain of triangle, rectangle and stroke

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a task to create chat. Here is the UI:

[image]

I've tried to draw rectangle and triangle and in layer list to combine this 2 drawables, but it looks very bad...

**Rectangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/message_cloud_client" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/message_cloud_client_stroke" android:width="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

**Triangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="90%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle"  >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="#dce7f7"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You need to read this http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: This isn't a place for an XML drawable, its a place for a 9 patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `Nine-patch` images instead of creating a layer-list. In a `Nine-patch' image you can indicate the rectangle that is grown or shrink when the image is resized. But the whole image is not affected. Here is the address of the tool:

`sdk\tools\draw9patch`

Open the file. Import your original image and set a rectangle inside the original images that is affected when the image is resized. (Do not include the edges of your picture).

Also you can do this with `Vector` images that is now available in support library.